# How to draw UIViewController in full screen when push from NavigationController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

my ViewController will start draw under of NavigationBar it will reduce ViewController to 436*320 pixels
how can i force it to draw in full screen 480*320

Answer (score 2):

You could hide the navigation bar:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: if i dont want to hide navigationbar?

Answer (score 1):

Modal view? `-presentModalViewController:animated:`, you can set the style (slide up, flip, dissolve, page curl) with the `modalTransitionStyle` property (on the view controller to become modal)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem is with the status bar and not the navigation bar..

Try to add the following lines in your info.plist file:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

This way the application will be in full-scream.

You also try:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```